# Get and print out the element using xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

```
<table id="versionId" class="displayTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" rules="groups" style="width:100%;border-right:1px solid #DFDFDF;border-left:1px solid #DFDFDF;">
<caption class="displayCaption">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="rowOdd">
<td style="width:1%">
<td style="width:15%;">
<span class="font">1</span>
</td>
<td style="width:12%">
<td style="width:10%">
<td style="width:10%">
<td style="width:13%">
<td style="width:18%">
=======
```

any way i can get that 1 and print out?

i tried out this `.//*[@id='versionId']/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()`:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='versionId']/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()")));
```

it return me with error:

The given selector .//*[@id='versionId']/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text() is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression ".//*[@id='versionId']/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/text()" is: [object XrayWrapper [object Text]]. It should be an element.

HELP D:

Comment: Maybe you should remove dot "**.**" before `//*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your xpath you are getting the text, not the element. To find the element you can use the following xpath: `//span[@class='font']`

If you need to print out the text then the code should be following:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='font']")).getText())
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help! this is the one im looking for!